# Can anyone see why I'm killing my buck regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, switching-regulator

I've tried hard, but I can't figure it out. The [buck regulator](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP62200_AP62201_AP62200T.pdf) runs for about about 1 s and then it dies with the buck regulator shorted to ground.

The LDO is working fine. If I power the LDO with 5.5 V, the board lights up and draws about 220 mA.

Relevant pics and datasheet are posted below. I would be super happy if someone could enlighten me.

[image: Schematic DC Input -> Buck -> LDO]

[image: Regulator Layout]

[image: Regulator Layout with copper pours]

Comment: What's the external input voltage and where does it come from?

Comment: I would like to handle 9V from to 18V from a wall wort.  I was testing with a 12V wall adaptor.

Comment: It won't work at 18 volts because that is the upper limit of performance with the absolute max being 20 volts and, any cable inductance and transients easily pushing it over 25 volts I expect. Measure the unloaded 12 volt output please.

Comment: Why is C42 upside down, or rather, why is it polarized to begin with? Also the feedback resistances are set for about 1V output, but you want it to be  5?

Comment: Why are you using a bridge rectifier? Are the wallwarts AC output at 50/60 Hz? Are the voltages you state AC voltages or DC voltages?

Comment: Unloaded it's showing 13.8 V.  The feedback resistors are indeed wrong in the schematic.  I fixed that during assembly.  As for the capacitor symbol, while I'll grant you it's not entirely correct, it really has no relation to the issue.

Comment: I'm using the bridge rectifier so that the polarity of the DC adapter doesn't matter.

Comment: Where is the 4.7 uH inductor on the layout? What hasn't it got a reference designator like the other components?

Comment: Are you hot-plugging the power adapter?

Comment: Yes, I am hot plugging the adapter.

Comment: C42 shouldn't be polarized at such a low capacitance, but if it is, it should be the other way around. If you kill C42, the converter can no longer turn its internal high-side FET fully on, so it will act like a source-follower and dissipate a significant amount of power, likely killing the IC from overtemperature. I disagree about the capacitor having "no relation to the issue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could potentially be due to your input capacitor - could you confirm what part number you're using?

From the datasheet:

> The RMS current rating of the input capacitor is a critical parameter and must be higher than the RMS input current

If the input capacitor is insufficient, the ripple current could result in large voltage spikes on the DC input to the buck converter, potentially exceeding the absolute maximum input voltage.

Comment: Input capacitor is part GRM188R61E106KA73D.

Comment: Notice the DC bias characteristics graph of that part:
https://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/productdetail?partno=GRM188R61E106KA73%23


At 13.8V DC bias, the capacitance drops by 86% (so down to 1.4uF).

Assuming a few ohms of impedance along the power supply, that will result in significantly more input ripple than there should be - I suspect this (combined with inductive overshoot) is killing the converter

Comment: I'll order a more robust part, figure out the TVS to keep the input voltage in line, and lll report back.

Comment: I removed the buck for now and placed the TVS diodes, and that clamps the voltage nicely at 9.5V.  I wish I had experimented with those first.

Comment: `I wish I had experimented with those first.` maybe you wish to not clamp a 12 V wall wart to 9.5 V, let alone an 18 V one.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the schematic the TVS diodes are on the input side of the bridge rectifier, rather than directly on the buck converter VIN pin. This is correct if you are trying to protect against externally applied spikes (eg ESD), but may not be as effective if the spikes are originating from the buck converter itself.

Comment: @greybeard -  The TVS is at 12V and then it drops a bit from there because of the bridge rectifier.  I can accept that only handling up to 12V adpaters.

Comment: @Andy - I understand what you are saying.  Looking at input capacitors, it's hard to find anything is a small package that maintains a good amount of capacitance at around 10 V.  I ordered an 15uF 0805, which I should be able to fit onto my 0603 footprint by scraping off some solder mask.  I also picked up a 10uF 1206 just in case, but that of course will be harder to fit in.

Comment: A combination of the 15uF cap and the TVS diodes has things working nicely.  I'll do some more extensive tests on the circuit when I have more time.  Thanks Andy.

Answer (score 0):

the ratio R14/R15 should be about 5.25 for a Vout=5V. Check those values as the ratio you have is actually too low at 1/6. Adjust the resistor values to set the correct output voltage then test again.

Comment: That was a mistake in the schematic.  I fixed it during assembly.

Comment: So what are the values for R14 and R15 now ?

Comment: R14 is 60k4 and R15 is 10k